# search multiple strings in a column on bash output

Tags: regex, awk, syntax, grep

I want to search multiple strings in 4th column using awk.
ex

```
ls -ltr | awk '$4 == /string1|string2/'
```

expression should return rows that contain either string1|2 in 4th column returned in output of ls -ltr.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please post the code which you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looking for an exact match, you need anchors on both sides

```
$ ... | awk '$4 ~ /^(string1|string2)$/'
```

or literally

```
$ ... | awk '$4=="string1" || $4=="string2"'
```

otherwise you'll get partial matches as well.

however, parsing `ls` output is usually discouraged and you can get the same most likely with `find`.

For partial matches (string1 or string2 appears as a substring of $4), go back to the first approach, to make it case insensitive keep string1 and string2 in lowercase and

```
... | awk 'tolower($4) ~ /string1|string2/'
```

Comment: Awesome - Thanks a lot. works solid for exact match.. how can I get partial matches? I needed that too.. and how can I ignore case in the strings that am searching?